# Delete drawable from ressources

Tags: android, drawable

I'm currently developing a picture managing app. At some point I will need to delete a drawable from the resources folder. Is this even possible? I cannot find any evidence that this is the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it even possible?

No. Resources are read-only at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Resources are the part of `APK` file, so since you cannot repack `APK` from Android system, you cannot modify (delete) it.